# Card View with VegaScrollFLowLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I am using **VegaScrollFlowLayout** layout in my app, I really liked the animation it is doing but I was thinking as if we can get the stack cards view with the following animation.

[image: Card Stack View Image]

So I want to have a view where I can have stack cards with the way VegaScrollFlowLayout animation : [VegaScrollFlowLayout](https://cocoapods.org/pods/VegaScrollFlowLayout)

If anyone knows any library, Let me know or can tell me any links from where I can develop something like this.